# Insufficient boundedness for integration via Darboux sums

Tags: real-analysis, summation

I have the simple integral $$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x}},$$ which I would like to constrain between two Darboux sums whose summands have absolute values not all zero. My attempt in doing so begins in noticing that, for the partition $\mathcal P : t_0 = 0 < t_1 = \frac{1}{2}< t_2 = \frac{2}{3} < \cdots < t_N = \frac{N-1}{N}$,
$$
0<\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x}}\leq\mathcal{U}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}},\mathcal{P}\right),
$$
where the former inequality is due to the nonnegativity of the integrand, while the latter just utilizes an upper Darboux sum. Note we require that $N\to\infty$ for the partition to "fill" $[0,1)$; further,
$$ \mathcal{U}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}},\mathcal{P}\right)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^N\sup_\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}([t_{k-1},t_k])(t_k-t_{k-1}) \\
    = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2}}}\left(\frac{1}{2}-0\right) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{3}}}\left(\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{2}\right) + \cdots + \lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{N-1}{N}}}\left(\frac{N-1}{N}-\frac{N-2}{N-1}\right) \\
    = \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=2}^N \sqrt{n}\left(\frac{(n-1)^2}{n(n-1)}-\frac{n(n-2)}{n(n-1)}\right) =  \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=2}^N \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(n-1)}, $$
which converges by the limit comparison test with $n^{-\frac{3}{2}}$, a convergent $p$-series summand, meaning $$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x}}$$ is bounded on both sides by reals, justifying its convergence to some value between.

Although I believe the right inequality is sufficient in my endeavor (is there a better one?), the left inequality very obviously does not obey my "sums whose summands have absolute values not all zero" criterion. Is there any way I can increase the value of my lower Darboux sum such that my integral is more reasonably bounded? How might I accomplish that? A new partition possibly? Also, apologies if any notation is ambiguous.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral Darboux sums are defined only for bounded functions, which yours is not. And your partition is not correctly written: $\frac{N-1}N=t_{N-1}$ and $t_N=1$, so the last sup in your sum is $+\infty$.